# Why Lookaheads in text with invalid tags does not work?

Tags: php, regex

With php making Lookaheads for line with invalid tags I need to find all words inside valid tags ( toyota) :

```
$subject = '<b>nissan</b> mazda dv <b>kia</b> <i>toyota</u> lorem';
{
    $validPattern = '~(?<=<[^>]>)([a-z]+)~im';;
} 
$result = preg_match_all($validPattern, $subject, $matches);
```

I got 3rd word “toyota” what is invalid (Invalid tags "toyota")

I changed expression adding "</\1>":

```
$validPattern = '~(?<=<[^>]>)([a-z]+)</\\1>~im';
```

But then nothing was found. Which valid decision ?

Comment: Hi, request you to please rephrase your question... your question is not clear..

Comment: Sorry, updated. Is it clear now ?

Comment: Your code giving `Nissan, Kia,Toyota`: https://3v4l.org/Ld1TGt

Comment: `(?<=` means lookbehind, lookahead should be `(?=`

Comment: _I got 3rd word “toyota” what is invalid (Invalid tags "toyota")_ : on what basis it is invalid? Question not clear. Please elaborate

Comment: Word "toyota"  is inside invalid tags : <i>...</u>. I suppose it must BE NOT FOUND

Comment: You can't use a backreference because you didn't capture the content of the starting tag (a look behind doesn't capture anything).  You could `<([^>])>[a-z]*</([^>])>` and then compare group 1 and 2 to see if they are different.

Comment: In PHP/PCRE you can also use [`\K` to reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K), it's a bit more efficient [`<(\w)>\K[a-z]+(?=</\1>)`](https://regex101.com/r/f6fkZl/1) also this would work if your capture is of variable length [like e.g. `\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/IdA0AP/1) where you can't use a lookbehind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to use backreference `\1` to match the opening tag, so you need to capture the opening tag first like this:

```
$validPattern = '~(?<=<([^>])>)([a-z]+)(?=</\\1>)~im';
```

Comment: Thanks! For me valid expression is "~(?<=<([^>])>)([a-z]+)(?=</\\1>)~im". As I use " I need to slash \1. Could you, please check/modify your code amd I will accept it.